# For which $z \in \mathbb{C}$ does $f(z) = |z|^2 +2z$ satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, partial-derivative, cauchy-riemann-equations

The task is as follows:

$$
\text{Check, for which } z\in\mathbb{C} \text{ function } f(z) = |z|^2 +2z \text{ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations.}
$$
I figured I need to transform $f(z)$ to $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + i \cdot v(x,y)$.

I started by transforming $f(z)$ to $f(x+iy)$ as such:
$$
f(x+iy) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + 2(x + iy) = (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+2x)+(2y)\cdot i
$$
Therefore:
$$
\begin{cases}
u(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} + 2x\\
v(x,y) = 2y
\end{cases}
$$

Unfortunately, when checking I started to check the Cauchy-Riemann equations I got the solution "$f(z)$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$" which is wrong.

Here's how I got this erroneous solution:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+2
\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 2
\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \Leftrightarrow x=0 \wedge y\neq0
$$
$$$$
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\\
-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0
\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \Leftrightarrow y=0 \wedge x\neq0
$$

And just like that I got the wrong answer. Where did I go wrong? How do I do this task correctly?

Comment: $|z| = x^2 + y^2$, not $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You calculated $|z|^2$ wrong.
It should be $x^2+y^2$.

Since $h(z)=2z$ is analytic, you can focus on $g(z)=|z|^2=x^2+y^2$ where $z=x+iy$.

Now $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $v(x,y)=0$ for $g=u+iv$. You can go on and check the C-R equations.